# Connecting to Facebook via the C# Facebook.Client LoginButton now failing?

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-runtime, facebook-c#-sdk

An existing WinRT app that was working using the Facebook.Client LoginButton Control now fails, with ‘Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains’ did something change on the backend service?

Answer (score 0):

After rewriting the creation of the facebook client and authorisation to use the SDK directly still had the same issue, so that ruled out the control. A rescan of similar questions revealed an answer  posted by David Alpert (see below) which solved the problem. The redirectURL being used in the call to GetLoginUrl was the same as the one below and this what I added. This fixed the SDK based connection, when I switched back to the control based authorisation that worked as well even though there is no specific use of the URL referenced.

This is David's answer:
This can also happen when the redirect_uri submitted with the https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth request is not present in the list of Valid OAuth redirect URIs under:
•   Settings >> Advanced >> Security
After much trial and error, when I added the redirect_uri that I was using (https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html in my case), I suddenly got to the step past this error.